# Every countable topological space is a Suslin space

Tags: general-topology

Definition:
A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be a **Suslin space** if it is Hausdorff and a continuous image of a Polish space (separable and completely metrizable).

A book about topology that I was reading mentioned that:

> every countable topological space is a Suslin space

First of all, **I am not too sure what "countable topological space" refers to** --- a first-countable or a second-countable topological space?

Second of all, I am not too sure how to prove the above statement. The book said that every countable topological space is a continuous image of the discrete space $\mathbb{N}$ (which is a Polish space?), so I am left with **showing that every countable topological space is Hausdorff**.

Third of all, **is $\mathbb{N}$ a Polish space**? It is separable because it has a dense countable subset ($\mathbb{N}$ itself), but I am not too sure whether it is completely metrizable.

My attempt at showing that every countable topological space is Hausdorff:
Let $a \in O_i$, $b \in O_j$ such that $a\neq b$.
To prove: $O_i \cap O_j=\phi$ for some $O_i$, $O_j$.
Suppose that $O_i \cap O_j \neq \phi$ for all $O_i$, $O_j$. Thus, $x_k \in O_i \cap O_j$, which implies that $x_k \in O_i$ and $x_k \in O_j$ for all $O_i$, $O_j$.
I am not too sure how to proceed from here. I think I'm supposed to show that this leads to the basis having an uncountable number of sets for a contradiction?

As you can tell, my head is spinning!

Comment: Strictly speaking the statement has an error. A countable set with its indiscrete topology is not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement is: any countable set with a Hausdorff topology is Suslin
Proof: $\mathbb N$ with the usual metric $d(n,m)=|n-m|$ is a a Polish space and has discerte topology , so any map on this is continuous. It is now clear that any countable set with a Hausdorff topology is the continuous image of the Polish space $\mathbb N$ with the usual metric.